# How to give priority to non-submit button over a submit button in material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form

I have a form which has a submit button. When I press the enter key, the form gets submitted. So far, so good.

However, if a user checks a certain value in the form, form-section OPT is shown. This section includes input field and a button "add to list".

What I want to achieve is that when the OPT form-section is open and a user clicks the enter-key, then the "add to list" button should be clicked instead of the "submit button".

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable solution, I think, is for the section that 'includes input field and a button "add to list"' to be its own `<form>`, nested inside the top-level `<form>`.  Then "add to list" can be a submit button, for that subform.  The browser should choose the correct submit button according to which form has focus (outer or inner).